# How to play an audio file starting at a specific time in pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I am using Pygame and i am able to play audio with it using the following  code

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('audio.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

This plays the audio but i want to play the audio from a specific time. Ik it can be done in vlc but i want it in pygame if possible.

Comment: You should start by reading [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`play` has 3 parameters: `(loops=0, start=0.0, fade_ms = 0)`. So

```
mixer.music.play(start=1.3)
```

`start` is in seconds.